# Extensible Map Widget (Cesium or Marble)?

Tags: qt, dictionary, kde-plasma, qgis, cesiumjs

I need to integrate an extensible map widget with my application running on a sized-down Linux ARM platform with around 1GB RAM, potentially no storage, potentially low bandwidth and connectivity. These limits are quite important. My application is developed using C++ and Qt5 with qml interfaces.

I've been looking at KDE Marble, Cesium and QGIS.
I don't think that QGIS is exactly my match, because I don't need to extensively edit geospatial data - rather, I need to display it in a nice widget. Plus QGIS is a GPL tool, which is, in my case, very restricting.

The map widget would be used, aside from normal virtual globe uses, to display custom layer data provided by some geolocalized sensors. I need to be able to create, display and edit paths (with waypoints) on the map view, it also needs to be touchscreen enabled.

Could you share your experience with developing Marble or Cesium or QGIS? Can you make a comparision of their pros/cons in relation to my needs?

I know it's a difficult question but any input is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm facing the same problem. After more than a year... what was your solution? QGIS, Marble or Cesium? I'm working with Qt 5.2 on embedded linux. Thanks

Comment: I ended up using Marble (and actively developing it). I've created my own library on top of Marble for my needs and I keep using it. At the time, Cesium was way too slow on target devices.

Comment: Thank you Adam, now I'm using Marble with QML, it is fast enough with my target.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use QGIS. It has the following modules:

- **QGIS core library**: basic GIS functionality
- **QGIS gui library**: adds reusable GUI widgets
- QGIS analysis library: high level tools for spatial analysis on vector and raster data
- **MapComposer**
- **QGIS network analysis library**: high level tool for build topology and analysis

You can compile the core and gui modules as you don't need advanced and complex features.

I recommend it because:

- It is highly modular and you can compile the modules which are necessary for
  your needs.
- QGIS also has many useful plugins which provides you whatever you
  like.
- QGIS has also a Globe plugin which shows maps on a 3D globe. It is
  not so mature but has good features.
- QGIS supports Android and is well suited for mobile and touch
  devices.
- It has also a fast developing community.
- New versions of QGIS support Qt 5.x
- It has a good documentation
- Adding new features and custom tools in so easy thanks to QgsMapTool

Comment: Thanks Nejat! QGIS looks quite powerful, but comes with a very infective GPL licence. I would probably prefer to make it a part of my program in a more integrated way rather then by using it as a plugin. However, I might in the end decide to use QGIS.